# Not able to function the media player properly in the background services

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have implemented the media player in my project and I want to play the music even when I close my application , but when I  kill my application  then it should stop playing the music.
My problem which I am facing is that my application starts playing the music again with the previous one playing already whenever I open my unkilled application again.What am i doing wrong ??

**My requirement is that the music should start playing as soon as i open the app,and it should keep on playing in the background even if i close(not killed) my app.But when i kill my app then the music should stop playing**

Here is my code -

**Main_activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String msg = "Android : ";

    private Button play,pause,restart;
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        restart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        restart.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    /** Called when the activity is about to become visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(msg, "The onStart() event");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    /** Called when the activity has become visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(msg, "The onResume() event");

    }

    /** Called when another activity is taking focus. */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(msg, "The onPause() event");
    }

    /** Called when the activity is no longer visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(msg, "The onStop() event");

    }

    /** Called just before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(msg, "The onDestroy() event");
        Log.d("mbound value",mBound+"");
        if (mBound) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,LocalService.class);
            stopService(intent);
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case(R.id.play):
                    if(mBound)
                        mService.start_mp();
                    break;
                case(R.id.pause):
                    if(mBound)
                        mService.pause_mp();
                    break;
                case (R.id.restart):
                    if(mBound)
                        mService.restart_mp();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalService.LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

**LocalService.java**

```
public class LocalService extends Service  {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Onbind called","");
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** Called when the service is being created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jingle);

    }

    /** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /** Called when all clients have unbound with unbindService() */
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return true;
    }


    /** Called when a client is binding to the service with bindService()*/
    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    /** Called when The service is no longer used and is being destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }
    public void start_mp(){
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    public void pause_mp(){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    public void restart_mp(){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jingle);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }


}
```

P.S.-I have applied the buttons in my application for the player functionality inside my app .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.Whenever I press my homebutton ,then my onstop() method is executed and I get whatever I aim at,on pressing back button the default action of android is to destroy the activity.

**Pressing the default back button of android device will call the finish() method of the activity and hence OnDestroy() will be called,by pressing the HomeButton the OnStop() method will be called.**